# Ant deploy with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant

```
mydep] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/Ant/bin/ant deploy
Buildfile: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/mydep/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource /Users/mannesiddhardha/.ant/lib/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

deploy:

BUILD FAILED
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/mydep/build.xml:12: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:com.salesforce:deploy
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/Ant/lib
        -/var/jenkins_home/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

Comment: Is your `ANT_HOME` set?

Comment: I have installed Ant in my mac "brew install Ant"

Comment: when i have looked in to "env", i haven't found ant ANT_HOME path.

Comment: even after setting my class path "ANT_HOME=/Users/mannesiddhardha/ANT-Pro/1.10.1" , i'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I have tried setting path in .bash_profile, "/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.1" , in that scenario i'm facing the class exception error's even i'm unable to compile my own ant .

Comment: my ant home location : "ant.home: /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.1/libexec
", even after setting it up for in ".bash_profile", if I ant it was leading to class error's.

Answer (score 0):

Add Antlib.jar file to the Ant_Home/lib folder and try it again.

Comment: I have antlib.xml in my ANT_HOME/lib, and there are some jar files, but I haven't found any antlib.jar .

Comment: <taskdef resource = "/Users/mannesiddhardha/ANT-Pro/antlib.xml" uri = "antlib:com.salesforce">
         <classpath>
            <pathelement location = "/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.1/libexec/lib/ant-salesforce.jar"/>
            </classpath>
         </taskdef>

Comment: ant -diagnostice

Comment: ant.core.lib: /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.1/libexec/lib/ant.jar
ant.home: /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.1/libexec

Comment: download and place it,if you can,and then check it once

Comment: [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.1/libexec/lib/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

Comment: Did you place the jar in Ant_Home/lib folder and you still facing the error. try to check the permissions of the jars in the folder or run the command using sudo

Comment: in my .bash_profile   #ANT_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.1/libexec
#ANT_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx512M"
#PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
#export ANT_HOME ANT_OPTS PATH

Comment: I have't found any antlib.jar file in my home lib, if you have any external download link for antlib.jar, pls provide

Comment: ant-salesforce.jar, ant.jar,  antlib.xml, i have these files in my ant_home lib

Comment: note: i'm running a jenkins job, for the sandbox deployment.

Comment: your xml file might have errors.can you check it once spellings etc.,

Comment: yeah, I had a look on that also, i haven't found any spell errors,

Comment: even after changing my <taskdef resource = "com/salesforce/antlib.xml"  i still unable to reslove this error.

Comment: [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource com/salesforce/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

Comment: Have you check this path /Users/mannesiddhardha/.ant/lib/ in your machine

Comment: yes, in this path in lib i have "ant-salesforce.jar" "antlib.xml"  these two files.

Comment: which version have you installed "ANT" in Jenkins, check it once

Comment: ant 1.10.1 , installed

Comment: have you configured it or installed it from Jenkins.Also check any sample build.xml running locally using "ant build". Run a Sample build.xml file and check whether it is successful or not

Comment: in jenkins from global tool configuration installing it automatically, and the same ant build.xml is fine when running from command line

Comment: and when i ran jenkins jobs with other build.xml files its is working, which dosen't have any task definitions included. Issue is occuring only when i'm trying for the deployment task.

Comment: here my target for this jenkins job is to take all the metadata from the github repo and place it in the sandbox, using an ant script for the deployment.

Comment: <taskdef resource = "com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri = "antlib:com.salesforce">
         <classpath>
            <pathelement location = "/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.10.1/libexec/lib/ant-salesforce.jar"/>
            </classpath>
         </taskdef>

Comment: In this Path "/Users/mannesiddhardha/.ant/lib/antlib.xml" or that xml is present???

Comment: Missing 'deployRoot' and 'zipFile'.  At least one is required.

Comment: yes it is present now, i'm getting the new error "Missing 'deployRoot' and 'zipFile'.  At least one is required.

Total time: 2 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE"